# Why is my javascript not invoked in my hooks except wp_head?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, hooks, wp-login-form

I am asking in the last instance because I am totally confused after not being able to invoke custom javascript functions for 2 days straight. I am new to Wordpress plugin developmnet as my background is Java and NodeJS and I simply can't understand why my code is not working.

I want to append a script in the html head based on the success event of a login, logout, and some other stuff. So I thought I could hook into the `wp_registration`, `wp_login` function and so on, enrich some data for the call and send this to a custom javascript. However the custom javascript is only invoked when I am calling the php function in the `wp_head` hook or by doing `add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function' );` and **never** in the hook function where I need the invocation.

For testing purposes I have installed a clean Wordpress instance and have added the following function in my plugin:

```
function my_function() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'hook-test.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script');

    $testVars = array(
            'test' => __('I should see something!'),
    );

    wp_localize_script('custom-script', 'test_script_vars', $testVars);
}
```

Now **how** can I use this in the form (or with an analogous functionality): `add_action('wp_login', 'my_function');` ?

The javascript is never executed. But when I am doing
`add_action('wp_head', 'my_function');` and `add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function');` it is...

I am welcoming any explanation and advice. Can't imagine this is so hard to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out it was not a matter of my code but of the fact that you cannot echo some custom javascript inside the 'wp_login' hook. What I did to solve this is to call `set_transient` inside my `wp_login` hook and then checking in the `wp_head` if there is any transient set. In this case I am echoing my javascript script and deleting the transient afterwards, as explained in this answer: [Run javascript code after wp_login hook?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38285/run-javascript-code-after-wp-login-hook)

My code now is:

```
/**
 * Register scripts used for pushing in the dataLayer
 */
function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/append_user_status.js' );
}

/**
 * Set transient in wp_login hook function
 */
function wp_login_hook( $user_login ) {
    set_transient( $user_login, '1', 0 );
}

/**
 * Add wp_login_hook as wp_login hook function
 */
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wp_login_hook' );

/**
 * Check if there is a transient set and echo js script in wp_head hook
 */
function echo_javascript_after_wp_login() {
    global $current_user;

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( ! get_transient( $current_user->user_login ) )
        return;

    $testVars = array(
            'test' => __('I should see something!'),
    );
    wp_enqueue_script ( 'custom-script' );
    wp_localize_script('custom-script', 'test_script_vars', $testVars);
    delete_transient( $current_user->user_login );
}

/**
 * Add echo_javascript_after_wp_login function as wp_head hook
 */
add_action ('wp_head', 'echo_javascript_after_wp_login', 9 );
```

If there are no additions to this, I will mark it as the answer to the question to help possibly other beginners in wordpress plugin development.

Comment: Haven't you tried the `login_enqueue_scripts` hook? You should hook into that one instead of `wp_head`. Also, adding a transient is a bit too much for this. A global variable would have been enough.

Comment: Uhm, have googled so much for this but never found **that**. Sounds exactly like what I was searching for as this looked like a bad workaround. If you might you can add an answer how to do it with `login_enqueue_scripts` and I gonna check it out and mark it as the answer if it works fine.

Comment: "A global variable would have been enough." This sounds interesting as well. As I said I am new to wordpress plugin development. Can you provide some information about how you would solve this with a global variable instead of a transient? The solution above is the only way which worked for my purposes I figured out in 3 days...

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has various hooks to enqueue scripts in different areas.

For the front end it's [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/), for the back end it's [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/), and for the login page it's [`login_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_enqueue_scripts/).

I don't know Ultimate Members, but if it uses `wp-login.php` the `login_enqueue_scripts` hook should work.

If `um_user_registration` is called somewhere else on the front end though, you should totally be able to enqueue some JavaScript when hooking into `um_user_registration`. It will just be added to the footer.

The same with the `wp_login` hook. As long as this hook is called before `wp_footer()` in your theme, you should be able to enqueue any scripts directly.

Comment: This still does not work for me. I have now `function add_js() { wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', '/path/to/my.js' ); }`  and `add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js', 1 );`. But again the js file is never enqueued in my html head. What am I missing? I feel like either something is broken or I am misusing something. Also using **login_head** instead of **login_enqueue_scripts** doesn't change anything as stated here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/custom-login-page-with-login_enqueue_scripts-not-working.

Comment: is there any update on this? I am really curious about why this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

That hook will be deprecated in Ultimate Member 2.0.

Beside that, have you added the actual hook with do_action in the header.php file of your theme? It is necessary for add_action to work.

I'm not sure it's the best soulution though.

I would rather register the script separately, "localize" it separately at um_user_registration (or its new equivalent on 2.0) and enqueue it conditionally using some function from Ultimate Member if available or a result of the registration stored ad hoc in usermeta if not available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am a total newbie in wordpress plugin programming, could you please give a coding example of your suggestion? I am totally messing up with where I should add and enqueue which scripts and so on.

Comment: By the way, I can also use the 'wp_signon' hook, so it should not be a problem that the ultimate member hook will be deprecated soon. I have updated my question.

Comment: Try to use 'my_function' and add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function'); within another function (let's say 'my_wrapper_function') that is associated with the wp_login hook: add_acttion('wp_login', 'my_wrapper_function');

Comment: I think that in my_wrapper_function you should also add a conditional check based on the data provided by the wp_login hook: if the wp_login user is equal to the current user, then add add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function');
Otherwise I am worried it would be loaded for everyone at the first login. You can also add a conditional check for the page where to load it.

Comment: mmm, not sure about the conditional check I suggested, I guess it always turns out to be true

Comment: Thank you for your help. As it turned out it was not a matter of my code but of the fact that I can't echo some javascript in the 'wp_login' hook. I had to some binding to the 'wp_head' or 'wp_footer' hooks to process my javascript. As I have showed in the answer.